# Looping through Hash, Can't Update Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enumeration

I'm trying to loop through this hash, and if a value is nil make it a blank string.

What's wrong?

`my_hash = {
"one"=>"foo",
"two"=>"bar",
"three"=>nil}`

`my_hash.each {|k,v| if v==nil then v="" end}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

v is a *local block variable* - it *evaluates* to the value from the hash pair, but is otherwise *separate* from the "hash slot"; as such, *re-assigning* to the variable does *not* affect the hash.

You need to use `my_hash[k] = ""` to cause a side-effect on the actual hash object.

---

An alternative to mutating the hash while it is being iterated (which is okay as long as keys are not changed) is to use a "functional" approach to create a new hash. This is for reference; not necessarily an argument to switch approaches.

```
# for each pair in the hash, yield a corresponding output pair
result = my_hash.map do |k,v|
    [k, if v.nil? then "" else v]
end

# create a new hash from the result, which is [[k,v],..]
my_hash = Hash[result]
```

Comment: `[k, v || ""]` if `false` isn't a possible value.

Comment: @MarkThomas That would indeed likely work here - I was interested in showing the use of `nil?`, which is why I left the form similar.

Comment: Not a fan of the ternary operator? `v.nil? ? '' : v`

Comment: @Matt Usually in C# I go, "I wish I had Ruby's if..then". Just stylistic preference, or perhaps a rebellion against more C-based language dialects.